"SEND_SMS" Permission Not Allowed in App - Android 15
I have an existing app in which using "SEND_SMS" permission i was able to send sms in background to the given number, After updating the OS to Android 15, This permission is not allowed for the app i.e ( In App Info "Allow" Option is disabled for SMS permission)
After searching for the resolution, found out that "SEND_SMS" is whitelisted permission.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SEND_SMS
Is there any way i can still use this permission in my app which is not an system app ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

In Android 15, the SEND_SMS permission is restricted to system apps and cannot be granted to regular apps, as it’s a whitelisted permission. To work around this, use the SmsManager API to send SMS via user-initiated actions, ensuring the user explicitly triggers the message. Alternatively, use an intent to open the default SMS app with the pre-filled message, allowing the user to send it manually. This approach aligns with Android's tightened security policies.
